# Mongodb aggregate $lookup $project and $match do not work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need your help. I am practicing very simple join method with filter on my two collection. It works without filter.
My mongodb query is mention below.

**Two Collection**

First collection

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24"),
    "company_name": "COMPANY 1",
    "company_detail_id": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5e5db61dbb9d1523f7d78e65") //NOTE: company_detail_id == programs._id
            }
    ],
    "is_deleted": false,
}
```

Second Collection

```
{
     "_id": ObjectId("5e5db61dbb9d1523f7d78e65"),
     "name": "PROGRAM 1",
     "is_deleted": false
}
```

**Query**

> ```
> var list = await dataModel.aggregate([
>             {
>                 $lookup: {
>                     from: "company_details",
>                     localField: "company_detail_id._id",
>                     foreignField: "_id",
>                     as: "programs"
>                 }
>             },
>             {
>                 "$project": {
>                             "_id": true,
>                             "company_name": true,
>                             "company_detail_id": true,
>                             "is_deleted": true,
>                             "programs._id": true,
>                             "programs.name": true,
>                             "programs.is_deleted": true
>                         }
>             },
>             {
>                 "$match": {
>                             "_id": "5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24",
>                             "is_deleted":false
>                             }
>             }
>         ]).skip(0).limit(10);
> ```

**Issue**

This query WORKS when

```
    "$match" : {} 
    or
    "$match" : { "company_name": "xyz" }
```

This query **NOT WORKING** when

```
    "$match" : { "_id" : "5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24" } 
    or
    "$match" : { "_id": "5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24", "is_deleted":false }
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
    "_id": "5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24",
    "company_name": "COMPANY 1",
    "company_detail_id": [
            {
                "_id": "5e5db61dbb9d1523f7d78e65" //NOTE: company_detail_id == programs._id
            }
    ],
    "is_deleted": false,
    "programs": [
            {
                 "_id": "5e5db61dbb9d1523f7d78e65",
                 "name": "PROGRAM 1",
                 "is_deleted": false
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found **SOLUTION**

I include

```
const {ObjectId} = require('mongodb');
```

Then in $match I use

```
"$match" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24") }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$match` stage with `{ "_id" : "5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24" }` as its part is not working because its trying to match an `ObjectId` with a string.

Since Mongoose is used here, convert that string to a valid mongodb `ObjectId` using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24')`.

Query:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var list = await dataModel
  .aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "company_details",
        localField: "company_detail_id._id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "programs",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: true,
        company_name: true,
        company_detail_id: true,
        is_deleted: true,
        "programs._id": true,
        "programs.name": true,
        "programs.is_deleted": true,
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ea18cd00715f152a6fcee24"),
        is_deleted: false,
      },
    },
  ])
  .skip(0)
  .limit(10);
```

[Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7MJzhN9NJI8)

Comment: Yeah, you posted the solution just as I was editing the query :). Also a suggestion: you don't have use a separate package `mongodb` to convert a string to `objectId`. Mongoose is sufficient.